# Может ли парадокс быть странным?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

Может ли парадокс быть странным?

1. **Конечно нет,** скажут составители учебных пособий, это **лексическая ошибка (плеоназм)**, ведь на греческом языке ***paradoxos*** – это как раз и есть необыкновенный, странный.

**ПАРАДОКС**, -а; м. [от греч. paradoxos - необыкновенный, странный] Неожиданное, непривычное, расходящееся с традицией, общепринятыми нормами рассуждение, мнение, вывод. Он часто говорит парадоксами. // Разг. Неожиданное явление, не соответствующее обычным представлениям. П. состоит в том, что металла выплавляем много, а его не хватает.

Составители даже **пример придумали**, вставив в текст отсутствующее слово: *Одним из **(странных)** парадоксов внутренней политики Александра I послевоенного времени стало то обстоятельство, что попытки обновления российского государства сопровождались установлением полицейского режима, позднее получившего название "аракчеевщины".*

2. **А какие же определения** может иметь слово «парадокс»?  Вот на одном ресурсе дается сочетаемость:  [https://kartaslov.ru/сочетаемость-слова/парадокс](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81)

Там есть определения **«странный, удивительный»**, но, может, это ошибка?

3. Посмотрим в [Нацкорпусе](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81)

«Странный парадокс» встречается, хотя и редко. Удивительно, что **Пастернак** его использует, вот бы у кого спросить!

*И только борьбой этих двух начал в ее душе могу я объяснить **странный парадокс**, что, уничтожая мои рисунки, она в то же время, вняв слезным просьбам моим, разрешила мне взять несколько уроков рисования.* [Л. О. Пастернак. Записи разных лет (1943)]

**Так точно ли это ошибка?**

Comment: Ну, Пастернак не аргумент против плеоназма, у классиков такое встречается ("Согласно кивнул головой" вместо просто "кивнул", например, есть и у Горького, и у Шукшина, и у Искандера). // Что касается "странного парадокса", то я бы такой оборот использовать не стал, но его можно оправдать: странный парадокс -- новый, непривычный, в отличие от каких-нибудь давно затёртых, уже не вызывающих ощущение "странности" парадоксов. // Замечу также, что плеоназм не всегда является лексической ошибкой, он может быть художественным приёмом. "-- Закрой глаза кожей -- и спи!" -- Платонов.

Comment: Я поняла вас так. Великим всё можно, все позволено, в том числе плеоназм, так что нечего нам на них равняться. Кроме того, у писателей это может быть художественным приемом. Вы же считаете сочетание ошибочным, сами его не используете (еще под критику попадешь), но для других допускаете некоторую условность – непривычный/новый парадокс. Что я могу сказать? «Новый парадокс» кажется мне сомнительной идеей – у нас нет списка привычных парадоксов.

Comment: К тому же я  допускаю для себя безусловную правильность сочетания «странный парадокс», и мне хотелось бы понять почему. Не могли бы вы объяснить высказывание Пастернака? Ошибка ли это, небрежность или все-таки сочетание, которое не казалось ему неправильным и недопустимым в той мере, как это понимается в наше время и пропагандируется как образец  плеоназма. Если можно, в виде ответа (за «вкусняшку» в десять или более  у.е.)

Comment: Привычные парадоксы -- это, к примеру, апории Зенона) // Что у Пастернака -- я не знаю и не рискну даже предполагать, так что ответа не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, если уж ответа не будет.  Мне вообще никто не отвечает... Наверное, лучше и не спрашивать.

Comment: Ну почему никто? Я иногда, а oleedd даже почаще. ☺

Comment: А вы ответили  сегодня на вопрос о сравнительном обороте? Не ответили! Сказали: "Нетушки!"  Только комментарии. Вот и здесь так же сказали...

Comment: Вы знаете, то ли из-за незнания переводов и этимологии, то ли от частотности использования некоторых плеоназных сочетаний в бытовой речи, мы (я) не часто обращаем внимание на их "неграмотность". Сейчас почему-то сразу не приходят в голову самые распространенные из них, но вот "странный парадокс", как мне чувствуется, имеет право быть...

Comment: Загадками говорите! Неграмотное сочетание, Пастернак просто не заметил "неграмотность", да?

Comment: Нет, я говорю о том, что некоторые плеоназные с точки зрения исторической лингвистики сочетания со временем могут стать нормой, ввиду их распространенности и поросшей мхом избыточности.

Comment: Вот завтра сама себе отвечу, чтобы доказать вам всем, что это корректное сочетание (может быть, отвечу).  Если уж говорить о парадоксах, то  и мыслить надо так же.

Comment: Дык я тоже за - за это сочетание!

Comment: Дык разве? Вы так туманно выражаетесь, что вас не поймешь.  Наверняка мои оппоненты принимают вас за своего.

Comment: Ну не знаю, сейчас просто я не слишком долго думаю, пиша :))  Но я же написал, что "странный парадокс" для меня норм.

Comment: Тогда напишите ответ. А вопрос я повторю: "Не могли бы вы объяснить высказывание Пастернака? Ошибка ли это, небрежность или все-таки сочетание, которое не казалось ему неправильным и недопустимым..." Можно коротко (одно-два предложения).

Answer (score 2):

*О сколько нам открытий чудных*

*Готовят просвещенья дух,*

*И Опыт, сын ошибок трудных,*

*И Гений, парадоксов друг…*

1829 г.

1. Кто-то однажды узнал (прочитал в словаре) о происхождении слова «парадокс»:  на греческом языке – это необыкновенный, странный.

И конечно же, сразу догадался, что **«странный парадокс» –  плеоназм**, причем не какой-нибудь там заурядный. Это – король плеоназмов, главный среди них, образцовый. И все ему поверили, потому что образцы и ориентиры нужны всегда, а иначе у нас будет спутанное сознание.

2. Но русский язык – **это не совсем греческий**, и значение слов в нем не остается неизменным. Парадоксальным стали называть необычное мышление, выходящее за рамки стандартной логики (оно оценивалось как негативное), а также явления, которые нельзя было объяснить стандартной логикой (и это было огорчительно).

Разум как бы признавал свою **ограниченность**: то ли знаний не хватает, то ли само мышление несовершенно. Вот гений – это «парадоксов друг!».

3. Но здесь мы разбираемся **со «странным парадоксом».** Оказывается, этому слову нужны определения – другими словами, нужна классификация. Ведь разные бывают парадоксы: (1) временные, исторические, логические; (2) забавные, любопытные, интересные; (3) известные, очередные, следующие.

И что удивительно, **странными они тоже бывают.** Это простое усиление признака, обычное дело в языке: очень странный, самый странный. К тому же повтор может быть художественным средством выразительности.

И в конце концов,  парадокс – это странное (необычное) явление, которое можно объяснить только странной (необычной) логикой. Получается как бы **дважды парадокс** – почему бы не подчеркнуть это.

4. И еще **о Пастернаке** – у него-то почему «странный парадокс»? Не знал, что это плеоназм, не заметил или намеренно употребил это сочетание? У таких людей **свободное мышление** – их уж точно не заставишь думать со всеми одинаково и всегда считать повтор плеоназмом.

Но и **особого смысла** он сюда, возможно, не вкладывал. Интересно, что этому слову в данном предложении требуется какое-нибудь **определение для равновесия фразы**, но использовать, к примеру, указательное местоимение (этот парадокс) он, вероятно, не захотел, то есть счел его неподходящим.

P. S. **Почему вообще был задан этот вопрос**. В задании было дано предложение и требовалось найти **лишнее слово**. Я быстро прочитала его, и в качестве кандидата выбрала указательное местоимение «то», которое в изъяснительных СПП часто бывает лишним. Но, увы, к местоимению вопросов не оказалось,  а вот «странный парадокс», который вычислили все, я просто не заметила…

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136773/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----).

Answer (score 0):

Греческое слово **παράδοξος** (парадоксос) происходит от греческих **παρά** (несмотря на, вопреки) и **δόξα** (мнение, ожидания, представление). Иными словами парадокс это мнение, рассуждение, которое расходится с общепринятым мнением и кажется нелогичным или противоречащим здравому смыслу.

Само слово парадокс выстраивает определенные ожидания. Например, парадокс дней рождения выстраивает определенные ожидания о, как нам кажется, маловероятном событии и показывает, что событие всё таки очень вероятно.

Поскольку парадокс рождает ожидания, парадокс также может быть странным и парадоксальным. Например, парадокс Монти Холла и вышеупомянутый парадокс дней рождения не являются парадоксами в научном смысле, поскольку в них отстутствует явное противоречие. После развенчания мнимого противоречия в нашей голове, сам факт возникновения этих парадоксов становится парадоксален.

Что какасается Пастернака, это выглядит как обычный плеоназм и не несёт какой-то нагрузки.

Comment: 1. Парадокс имеет два значения: мнение и явление (см. словарь). Мое мнение, к примеру, очень часто расходится с общепринятым. Тогда это парадокс? Нет пока, надо доказать что оно "кажется нелогичным или противоречащим здравому смыслу". А чей здравый смысл берется в качестве образца? Вот здесь неувязочка – абы какой меня не устраивает. И что значит "кажется нелогичным",  и опять же кому! Нелогичность надо доказывать, а в нашем обществе с этим проблемы. 2. Логику в школе не изучают,  а здесь нужно строгое доказательство, не каждый возьмется.

Comment: А если и возьмется, то кто его будет слушать и понимать?  Замкнутый круг.  Поэтому понятие парадокса у нас чисто бытовое, в том числе у Пастернака. И вопрос-то не о научных парадоксах, а   о нашей  повседневной оценке ситуации. А вот требование к речевой правильности "строго научные". Вот вам еще один «парадокс».  И вопрос-то  был именно о речевой правильности, а не о парадоксах вообще. Надо было понять, откуда всё это пошло. У нас "грамотный человек" обязан: знать правильное ударение (звонИт), не одевать пальто и не говорить "странный парадокс". Это всё.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть.

Парадокс — это когда что-то происходит не так, как должно происходить. Например, молот больше молотка, а размер слов — наоборот. Это известный парадокс. Думаю, это не тот парадокс, который следует считать странным.

Парадокс может быть очевидным для учёных, но странным для обычных людей.
Парадокс может быть странным для исследователя парадоксов (он не может с ним разобраться).

Есть неполные плеоназмы (не термин). Когда почти во всех случаях плеоназм, но иногда нет. Зависит от контекста. "Улыбка на лице" из той же серии.

Comment: В парадоксах разбираются ученые (это лингвистические парадоксы), а у нас к ним приравняли бытовые парадоксы и требуют от школьников не называть их странными. Причем раньше вроде бы не требовали. Вот это парадокс нашей образовательной системы.

Comment: Бывают простые парадоксы. Это слово употребляют, когда что-то идёт не так, как должно, а наоборот.

Comment: Да это многозначное слово, им все пользуются совершенно свободно. Но только на экзамене странный парадокс - это плеоназм.

Comment: Им стоит избегать неполных плеоназмов, если не было такой темы. Да что там говорить, такого, наверно, и в учебниках/справочниках нет.